# Viewing MHTML (.mht) file in web page

Tags: configuration, cross-browser, viewer, content-disposition, mhtml

Technology at my disposal:

**HTML, HTML5, LINQ, C#, ASP.net, Razor, jQuery, Javascript, Entity**

I would like to view my MHTL file on my website.  Is this possible?

I tried using IFrame but this only forced a download of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an browser plugin or preference, such as the following:

- [unMHT](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unmht/) and [Mozilla Archive Format](http://maf.mozdev.org/documentation.html) plugins for Firefox
- [MHTML preference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture) in the following URL for Chrome or Opera:

  ```
  chrome://flags/#save-page-as-mhtml
  ```
- [MHTML URIs](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-data-uris-in-all-browsers) for IE, (but [registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2547338) and [HTTP headers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2846926) may need configuration)